# Is there a better way to iterate over two lists, getting one element from each list for each iteration?

Tags: python, list, iteration

I have a list of Latitudes and one of Longitudes and need to iterate over the latitude and longitude pairs.

Is it better to:

- A. Assume that the lists are of equal lengths:

  ```
  for i in range(len(Latitudes)):
      Lat,Long=(Latitudes[i],Longitudes[i])
  ```
- B. Or:

  ```
  for Lat,Long in [(x,y) for x in Latitudes for y in Longitudes]:
  ```

(Note that B is incorrect. This gives me all the pairs, equivalent to `itertools.product()`)

Any thoughts on the relative merits of each, or which is more pythonic?

Answer (score 308, accepted):

This is as pythonic as you can get:

```
for lat, long in zip(Latitudes, Longitudes):
    print(lat, long)
```

Comment: In Python 2.x you might consider itertools.izip instead (zip does the same thing in Python 3.x).

Comment: @NicholasRiley: care to mention why?

Comment: It uses less memory and may be faster; it creates an iterator rather than an intermediate list.

Comment: what if additionally I want the index `i`? Can I wrap that zip in enumerate?

Comment: @CharlieParker Yes you can.

Comment: for index, (lat,long) in enumerate(zip(Latitudes, Longitudes)):

Answer (score 53):

Another way to do this would be to by using `map`.

```
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> b
[4, 5, 6]
>>> for i,j in map(None,a,b):
    ...   print i,j
    ...
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

One difference in using map compared to zip is, with zip the length of new list is
same as the length of shortest list.
For example:

```
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 9]
>>> b
[4, 5, 6]
>>> for i,j in zip(a,b):
    ...   print i,j
    ...
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

Using map on same data:

```
>>> for i,j in map(None,a,b):
    ...   print i,j
    ...

    1 4
    2 5
    3 6
    9 None
```

Comment: is it possible to do it like: 14,15,16??

Comment: The map-solution didn't work in python 3.6. I had to use itertools.zip_longest(a,b) for the same effect.

Answer (score 22):

Good to see lots of love for `zip` in the answers here.

However it should be noted that if you are using a python version before 3.0, the `itertools` module in the standard library contains an `izip` function which returns an iterable, which is more appropriate in this case (especially if your list of latt/longs is quite long).

In python 3 and later `zip` behaves like `izip`.

Answer (score 15):

in case your Latitude and Longitude lists are large and lazily loaded:

```
from itertools import izip
for lat, lon in izip(latitudes, longitudes):
    process(lat, lon)
```

or if you want to avoid the for-loop

```
from itertools import izip, imap
out = imap(process, izip(latitudes, longitudes))
```

Answer (score 7):

Iterating through elements of two lists simultaneously is known as zipping, and python provides a built in function for it, which is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip).

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y = [4, 5, 6]
>>> zipped = zip(x, y)
>>> zipped
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
>>> x2, y2 = zip(*zipped)
>>> x == list(x2) and y == list(y2)
True
```

[Example is taken from pydocs]

In your case, it will be simply:

```
for (lat, lon) in zip(latitudes, longitudes):
    ... process lat and lon
```

Answer (score 6):

```
for Lat,Long in zip(Latitudes, Longitudes):
```

Answer (score 5):

This post helped me with `zip()`. I know I'm a few years late, but I still want to contribute.  This is in Python 3.

Note: in python 2.x, `zip()` returns a list of tuples; in Python 3.x, `zip()` returns an iterator.
`itertools.izip()` in python 2.x == `zip()` in python 3.x

Since it looks like you're building a list of tuples, the following code is the most pythonic way of trying to accomplish what you are doing.

```
>>> lat = [1, 2, 3]
>>> long = [4, 5, 6]
>>> tuple_list = list(zip(lat, long))
>>> tuple_list
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Or, alternatively, you can use `list comprehensions` (or `list comps`) should you need more complicated operations.  List comprehensions also run about as fast as `map()`, give or take a few nanoseconds, and are becoming the new norm for what is considered Pythonic versus `map()`.

```
>>> lat = [1, 2, 3]
>>> long = [4, 5, 6]
>>> tuple_list = [(x,y) for x,y in zip(lat, long)]
>>> tuple_list
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
>>> added_tuples = [x+y for x,y in zip(lat, long)]
>>> added_tuples
[5, 7, 9]
```