# Is there a good way of iterating through several lists(where sometimes they are single valued) in python

Tags: python, numpy

So basically my question relates to 'zip' (or izip), and this question which was asked before....

[Is there a better way to iterate over two lists, getting one element from each list for each iteration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919044/is-there-a-better-way-to-iterate-over-two-lists-getting-one-element-from-each-l)

If i have two variables - where they either are a 1d array of values length n, or are a single value, how do i loop through them so that I get n values returned.

'zip' kindof does what I want - except that when I pass in a single value, and an array it complains.

I have an example of what I'm aiming for below - basically i have a c function that does a more efficient calculation than python.  I want it to act like some of the numpy functions - that deal ok with mixtures of arrays and scalars, so i wrote a python wrapper for it.  However - like I say 'zip' fails.  I guess in principle I can do some testing of the input s and write a different statement for each variation of scalars and arrays - but it seems like python should have something more clever.... ;)  Any advice?

```
"""
    Example of zip problems.
"""

import numpy as np
import time

def cfun(a, b) :
    """
        Pretending to be c function which doesn't deal with arrays
    """
    if not np.isscalar(a)   or  not np.isscalar(b)  :

        raise Exception('c is freaking out')
    else :

        return a+b

def pyfun(a, b) :
    """
        Python Wrappper - to deal with arrays input
    """

    if not np.isscalar(a)   or  not np.isscalar(b) :
        return np.array([cfun(a_i,b_i) for a_i, b_i in zip(a,b)])

    else :

        return cfun(a, b)

    return cfun(a,b)


a = np.array([1,2])
b= np.array([1,2])
print pyfun(a, b)

a = [1,2]
b = 1
print pyfun(a, b)
```

**edit :**

Many thanks everyone for the suggestions everyone.  Think i have to go for np.braodcast for the solution - since it seems the simplest from my perspective.....

Comment: I changed your `'''` to `"""` so SO's renderer would like it.  As a side note, `"""` is actually preferred to `'''`  I think

Comment: [PEP 257](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) describes docstrings. It says... `For consistency, always use """triple double quotes""" around docstrings. Use r"""raw triple double quotes""" if you use any backslashes in your docstrings. For Unicode docstrings, use u"""Unicode triple-quoted strings"""`

Comment: @MarkHildreth -- PEP 257.  I knew it was in a PEP somewhere, but when I didn't find it in PEP8, I began to wonder if I was making it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you use numpy, you don't need `zip()` to iterate several arrays and scalars. You can use `numpy.broadcast()`:

```
In [5]:

list(np.broadcast([1,2,3], 10))

Out[5]:

[(1, 10), (2, 10), (3, 10)]

In [6]:

list(np.broadcast([1,2,3], [10, 20, 30]))

Out[6]:

[(1, 10), (2, 20), (3, 30)]

In [8]:

list(np.broadcast([1,2,3], 100, [10, 20, 30]))

Out[8]:

[(1, 100, 10), (2, 100, 20), (3, 100, 30)]
```

Comment: I ran into this after a generator I previously used no longer worked after a `numpy` upgrade. This is really useful, but it seems like the way the question is stated and titled obscures finding this answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to force broadcasting, you can use `numpy.lib.stride_tricks.broadcast_arrays`. Reusing your `cfun`:

```
def pyfun(a, b) :
    if not (np.isscalar(a) and np.isscalar(b)) :
        a_bcast, b_bcast = np.lib.stride_tricks.broadcast_arrays(a, b)
        return np.array([cfun(j, k) for j, k in zip(a_bcast, b_bcast)])
    return cfun(a, b)
```

And now:

```
>>> pyfun(5, 6)
11
>>> pyfun(5, [6, 7, 8])
array([11, 12, 13])
>>> pyfun([3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8])
array([ 9, 11, 13])
```

For your particular application there is probably no advantage over Rob's pure python thing, since your function is still running in a python loop.

Answer (score 0):

A decorator that optinally converts each of the arguments to a sequence might help. Here is the ordinary python (not numpy) version:

```
# TESTED
def listify(f):
  def dolistify(*args):
    from collections import Iterable
    return f(*(a if isinstance(a, Iterable) else (a,) for a in args))
  return dolistify

@listify
def foo(a,b):
  print a, b

foo( (1,2), (3,4) )
foo( 1, [3,4] )
foo( 1, 2 )
```

So, in your example we need to use `not np.isscalar` as the predicate and `np.array` as the modifier. Because of the decorator, `pyfun` always receives an array.

```
#UNTESTED
def listify(f):
  def dolistify(*args):
    from collections import Iterable
    return f(*(np.array([a]) if np.isscalar(a) else a for a in args))
  return dolistify

@listify
def pyfun(a, b) :
    """
        Python Wrappper - to deal with arrays input
    """

    return np.array([cfun(a_i,b_i) for a_i, b_i in zip(a,b)])
```

Or maybe you could apply the same idea to `zip`:

```
#UNTESTED
def MyZip(*args):
  return zip(np.array([a]) if np.isscalar(a) else a for a in args)

def pyfun(a, b) :
    """
        Python Wrappper - to deal with arrays input
    """

    return np.array([cfun(a_i,b_i) for a_i, b_i in MyZip(a,b)])
```