# How to avoid StopIteration Error in python

Tags: python, iteration, stopiteration

I have a line that is pulling in variables from multiple lists and I want it to avoid the `StopIteration` error that comes up so that it can move onto the next line. At the moment I am using the break function, this avoids the `StopIteration`, but only gives me the first item in the list and it leaves a blank line after it, if i was to print it out.

Here are two of my iterations that have the same problem.

```
def compose_line5(self, synset_offset, pointer_list):
    self.line5 = ''''''
    for item in pointer_list:
        self.line5 += '''http://www.example.org/lexicon#'''+synset_offset+''' http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#has_ptr '''+pointer_list.next()+'''\n'''            
        break
    return self.line5

def compose_line6(self, pointer_list, synset_list): 
    self.line6 = ''''''
    for item in synset_list:
        self.line6 += '''http://www.example.org/lexicon#'''+pointer_list.next()+''' http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#pos '''+synset_list.next()+'''\n'''                      
        break
    return self.line6
```

This is the error I get without the break:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wordnet.py", line 225, in <module>
    wordnet.line_for_loop(my_file)
  File "wordnet.py", line 62, in line_for_loop
    self.compose_line5(self.synset_offset, self.pointer_list)
  File "wordnet.py", line 186, in compose_line5
    self.line5 += '''http://www.example.org/lexicon#'''+self.synset_offset+''' http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#has_ptr '''+self.pointer_list.next()+'''\n'''
StopIteration
```

Is there a quick fix for this or do I have to catch exceptions for every method I use the iter() in?

Comment: Why are you calling self.pointer_list.next() and passing in a pointer_list?

Comment: Sorry, Typo!! makes no difference anyways!

Comment: There is no need to triple quote anything here; you are not including line breaks and the quoting is overly verbose. Better still, use string formatting: `'http://www.example.org/lexicon#{}  http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#has_ptr{}\n'.format(synset_offset, pointer_list.next())`.

Comment: There needs to be two whitespaces in each line, I am converting them to triple format and it wont accept any full lines, can I leave spaces in that formatting?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In `compose_line5`, instead of `pointer_list.next()`, use `item` - you are already iterating over `pointer_list`.

For `compose_line6`, it seems you want to iterate over two lists at the same time.  Use the top answer from [Is there a better way to iterate over two lists, getting one element from each list for each iteration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919044/is-there-a-better-way-to-iterate-over-two-lists-getting-one-element-from-each-l)
(I'm assuming both lists are the same length)

Yes, the iterator protocol will raise `StopIteration` (not an error, just an exception signalling the end of the iteration) if you call `.next()` on it manually. The pythonic way to use it is to use it as a normal iterator (for example, looping over it) and not call `.next()` on it.

Your code has a few issues beyond that that you may want to look at - look at http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

For example, no need to use `''''''` when `''` suffices.  Instead of doing `+=`, you may want to create a list then join in the end.  Not sure why you store things in self if you're just returning them from the function.