# How to iterate over two different-size lists to get a new list?

Tags: python

Now I wish to build a list containing `100*50` 2-D points. I have tried the following:

```
[(x+0.5, y+0.5) for x, y in zip(range(100), range(50))]
```

This only gives me 50*50 points. I found the reason accounting for this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1919402/2881553) that pointed out

> for zip the length of new list is same as the length of shortest list.

What is **the most Pythonic** way of getting my desired `100*50` points correctly?

Comment: use itertools.izip_longest()

Comment: For future reference, you're looking for the cartesian product, not lockstep iteration.

Answer (score 10):

Well, I think you want `itertools.product` instead of `zip`.

`itertools.product` calculates the cartesian product of the two lists and will give you the total 100*50 points.

The way you would do this would be

```
import itertools
[(x+0.5,y+0.5) for x,y in itertools.product(range(100),range(50))]
```

You could also do, nested for loops, but in general I'd say itertools.product is both more extensible and more pythonic (flat is better than nested)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way with less additions (just 150 compared to 5000)

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> list(product(map(.5.__add__, range(100)), map(.5.__add__, range(50))))
[(0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 1.5), (0.5, 2.5), (0.5, 3.5), (0.5, 4.5), (0.5, 5.5), (0.5, 6.5), (0.5, 7.5), (0.5, 8.5), (0.5, 9.5),...
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a loop for `x` and one for `y`:

```
>>> points = [(x+0.5, y+0.5) for x in xrange(100) for y in xrange(50)]
>>> len(points)
5000
>>> 100 * 50
5000
```

Answer (score 2):

Two loops.

```
[(x+0.5, y+0.5) for x in range(100) for y in range(50))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use numpy.meshgrid:

```
import numpy as np
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0,100,1),np.arange(0,50,1))
```