# How do you alter a variable name in a loop in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I having trouble figuring out how to do what is probably a simple thing.
I may have not have phrased the question well so i will just demonstrate what I want to do in the code below:

```
    x = 1
    while x != 10:
        y = x
        x = x + 1
```

I problem is that I want there to be a number after y, which is equal to x.

So when x = 1:
y1 = 1

And when x = 2:
y2 = 2

This code is the simplest way I think I can show my question but your answer will help me be able to run my code like I want to.
I just want you to keep in mind that I will NOT accept this answer:

```
    x = 1
    while(x != 10):
        if x = 1:
            y1 = 1
        elif x = 2:
            y2 = 2
        elif x = 3:
            y3 = 3
        (etc...)
```

The whole purpose of this question is to avoid using the process above.
I appreciate your time.

Comment: Use a dictionary?

Comment: how would you suggest?

Comment: You've got to be designing something wrong if you want dynamic variable names. Maybe expand more on what you are trying to do with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create lists from a list of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14241133/how-can-i-create-lists-from-a-list-of-strings)

Comment: What I suggested is one of many possible duplicates, see for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26850361/dynamically-assigning-variable-names . The bottom line is always "use a dictionary [or a list]" instead of generating dynamic variable names.

Comment: Which is why you use a dictionary, so that you can look up the value there instead. `y = {}, for .. : y[x] = x`. What is the problem you think this is the solution to?

Comment: Dictionaries appear to work thank you, but is there also a way to do it so that you can type print(y1), after you find it in a dictionary?

Comment: "*What I need is for the variable assignment name to be changed every time*": no, you don't. See also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7S94ohyErSw .

Comment: I said need, not want...

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem.

Answer (score -1):

Use dictionaries:

```
    y = {}
    x = 1
    while x < 10:
        y[x] = x
        x += 1

    >>> y = {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9}
```

Here, you can access the different y values by their keys: y[1], y[2], etc.

Or, use lists:

```
    y = []
    x = 1
    while x < 10:
        y.append(x)
        x += 1    

    >>> y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Here you can access each y value using their index(starting at 0)

Comment: Is this not what you wanted?