# Iterate through 2 lists at once in Python

Tags: python, list, iteration

I want to share/divide a specific amount to the members of two Python lists.  The members of list1 will have double share each, while the members of list2 will have single share each, then print out the result, with name and value allocated.  The following is my sample code:

```
reminder = float(85000)

list1 = ['Designer', 'Coder', 'Supervisor']
list2 = ['Artist', 'Attendant', 'Usher]

for i,j in list1 and list2:
    print(i, (reminder/9)*2)
    print(j, (reminder/9)*1)
```

When I ran the above code I got an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\reminder.py", line 6, in <module>
    for i,j in list1 and list2:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I searched previous posts on same topic but could't come across a solution.

How do I go about it please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a better way to iterate over two lists, getting one element from each list for each iteration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919044/is-there-a-better-way-to-iterate-over-two-lists-getting-one-element-from-each-l) or [How can I iterate through two lists in parallel in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-can-i-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel-in-python)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use [zip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) built-in function.

```
for i, j in zip(list1, list2):
    print(i, (reminder/9)*2)
    print(j, (reminder/9)*1)
```

Comment: I am grateful for the timely response.