# How do I loop through 2 arrays?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have 2 different arrays and I need help printing both of them

```
Route = ["Bus A","Bus B","Bus C","Bus D","Bus E","Bus F"]
DaysLate = [ [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6] ]
```

is there a way I can get this output?

```
Bus A 1
Bus B 2
Bus C 3
Bus D 4
Bus E 5
Bus F 6
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919044/is-there-a-better-way-to-iterate-over-two-lists-getting-one-element-from-each-l

Comment: I dont understand his code, cant be a duplicate because this is simpler?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a better way to iterate over two lists, getting one element from each list for each iteration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919044/is-there-a-better-way-to-iterate-over-two-lists-getting-one-element-from-each-l)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Route = ["Bus A","Bus B","Bus C","Bus D","Bus E","Bus F"]
DaysLate = [ [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6] ]

for i,j in zip(Route,DaysLate):
    print(i, j[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i in range(6):
    print(Route[i], DaysLate[i][0])
```

Comment: Will this work perfectly if the length of the list is greater than 6?

Comment: oh ok sorry it was because I forgot the indent, works

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the function `chain.from_iterable()` from `itertools` module to chain all sublists into a single sequence:

```
for i, j in zip(Route, itertools.chain.from_iterable(DaysLate)):
    print(i, j)
```

Alternatively you can use a star `*` to unpack sublists:

```
for i, j in zip(Route, DaysLate):
    print(i, *j)
```